# Rendering Problems of android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout

Tags: java, android, android-layout

i'm facing problem after upgrading the android studio to 2.2.3
problem is using **android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout** 
it shows this error

> The following classes could not be found:
>   - android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)
>   - android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)  Tip: Try to build the project.  Tip: Try to
>   refresh the layout.
>   \app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml" in attribute "imeActionId" is not a valid integer

i tried to fix build path but didn't work for me.
when i build and run  it shows

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout" on path:
>   DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/fitness.aclass.fitness-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib,
>   /system/lib]]
>                         at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>                         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
>                         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:571)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482) 
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
>                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284) 
>                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
>                         at fitness.aclass.fitness.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:11) 
>                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6092) 
>                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2468) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2595) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470) 
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5624) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754) 
>                         Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
>                         at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
>                         at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
>                         at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
>                         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
>                                 ... 22 more
>                      Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available

this is my build.gradle (App Module)

```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "fitness.aclass.fitness"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Any solution for this.!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**CoordinatorLayout** is part of design library. So you should add

`implementation' com.android.support:design:28.0.0'`

or `24.2.0` version if you need to use outdated version for some reason.

Comment: i cannot use 25.2.0 because compile version is 24.

Comment: so i use 24 and your answer really helped. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try to clean project from Build menu some time due to gradle build caching it happens. 
and one more thing try to use latest one as they have resolved many issues.

Comment: @Divers Read the question, its not about library or version of it. and i said what i have faced, don't be jealous.

Comment: I'm just stating the fact, Im not jealous. You can clean gradle build and cache 1 000 000 times, but if you use class which is not presented in project - you will see exception as above. So your answer is completely wrong.

Comment: @Divers So you are saying CoordinatorLayout was not available in v24. so for your info it was added in v22.2.0. check change log before putting finger on some one.

Comment: No, Im saying that coordinator layout is part of `'com.android.support:design'` not part of `com.android.support:appcompat-v7` or any other library.